# Android: call onCreate() from onResume()

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate, onresume

My initial setup related to UI takes place in `OnCreate()`, but before the UI appears I need to grant permission to the app from `Settings` . I'm using `Service` to start the `MainActivity`(which contains fragment) from the `Settings` as soon the the permission is granted, but when MainActivity again appears, only `onResume()` from the fragment gets called, whereas I have done all setup in `onCreate()`. What should I do?

Comment: Though I don't see why you need to reinitialize views again nonetheless `onCreate()` is a `lifecycle` method. Don't confuse it with regular function rather create a function to initialize and call the same function from `onResume()`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to not opening the fragment, unless the permission is granted.